# ¿como puedo unir listas dentro de un ciclo?

Tags: lista, bucle-for

iré al grano , tengo un ciclo for que me da listas , pero yo quisiera
de alguna forma poder unir todas esas listas,cuando hago print me da algo literalmente asi en el terminal:

[lista1]
[lista2]

[lista3]....etc

quisiera saber alguna manera de poder hacer que fuera algo asi:

[lista1,lista2,lista3]

adjunto el codigo por si es que no se entiende bien:

```
 def lectura():
        archivo=open("millonario.txt","r")
        lectura=archivo.readlines()
        #lectura del archivo
        return lectura

    def preguntas(lectura):
        for i in range(0,15):
            leer=(lectura[i])
            leerAlista=leer.split("/")
            preguntas=leerAlista[0:1]
            print(preguntas)

        return preguntas 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        lectura=lectura()
        preguntas=preguntas(lectura)
```

si se preguntan , son 15 preguntas en un block de notas cada una en cada 
linea

linea 1: pregunta1

linea 2: pregunta2

linea n: pregunta n , etc....

si alguien podria ayudarme muchas gracias!!

Comment: Puedes hacer `preguntas=[]` antes del bucle, y luego dentro de él extender la lista con cada una de las nuevas listas que vas encontrando, así: `preguntas.extend(leerAlista[0:1])`, si no me equivoco (no puedo probar el código porque no tengo tu fichero y desconozco su estructura, además de que no estoy del todo seguro de lo que buscas)

Comment: me daba miedo porque soy muy malo explicando , pero use lo que me dijiste y me funcionó a la perfeccion ,muchas gracias x mil :)

Comment: Revertí tu edición, no queda claro por que pusiste *respondido*, te invito amablemente a que si encontraste la respuesta consideres publicarla